# onActivityResult Implementation Does Not Function As Expected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, mediastore, onactivityresult

I'm attempting to use onActivityResult in order to launch the Android Gallery in order to display either photos - or videos depending on the ImageButton selected.

The problem is when attempting to open a photo it's attempting to launch the video player and I'm unsure why.

P.S.

Videos can be launched an played successfully using the video ImageButton.

```
private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 1;


ImageButton pb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photos);
    pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
        }
    });

    ImageButton vb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.video);
    vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intentGallery = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intentGallery.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(intentGallery, 1);

        }

    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
        {
            Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(selectedVideo, "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(selectedImage, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: maybe you messed up with the request codes?

Comment: SELECT_PHOTO = ? as you are passing request code "1" for video, hope that is also not equal to 1

Comment: Title implies that Google messed up onActivityResult and no one else saw the bug until now? Funny.

Comment: That's not what I'm implying at ALL - my implementation of it is not working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 1;
```

They need to be different, having a value "1" means they go into the same "if" `onActivityResult()`.

Also, its playing only video as that is your first "if" condition inside `onActivityResult()`, which will always end up being true with:

```
startActivityForResult(intentGallery, 1);  
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Pass both properly as you compare them.  Try it:

```
private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 2;

startActivityForResult(intentGallery, SELECT_VIDEO);  
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Should get [some help from this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

SLECT_VIDEO and SELECT_PHOTO cannot be same....